# VNET Integration for Azure function using Consumption plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, vnet

My azure function is running on a Consumption plan and it needs to access a resource running on a VM on a Azure VNET. The resource cannot be exposed via http.

Is there a solution other then switching to App Service Plan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, it is impossible. The VNet Integration feature requires a Standard, Premium, or Isolated pricing plan. Now, Consumption plan  is not supported.

If it's very import for you, you could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/15616044-add-vnet-integration).

Comment: Please vote up this feedback - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/15616044-add-vnet-integration

Comment: Is this still accurate more than 2 years later?

Comment: Terrible implementation by Microsoft. The only true "serverless" Azure Function is "Consumption plan". Not enabling VNET integration (virtually all DBs are behind VNETs) is rendering Azure Functions as completely useless. Why is Azure forcing me to by servers instances? wrong MSFT, just wrong.

Comment: BTW, this feedback was blocked my MSFT so no one can upvote. Shame.

Comment: Seems like they are working on this, see this link in here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/646#issuecomment-465801398

Comment: Is this still true in 2023?

Answer (score -1):

Azure Functions Premium was announced in Oct 2018 at Ignite. It allows Consumption-style scaling + VNet integration. Sign up for private preview here: https://aka.ms/functionspremium

Comment: Azure Functions "Premium plan" is not serverless. You still need to buy server instances and pay for 99% of unused CPU and Memory for 99% of the cases. Most people use 2-3 simple functions that run a fraction of the time. This forces them to pay for a full server instance, meaning Azure Functions is not really serverless.

Comment: Curious where your "most people" stat comes from - but thanks for the downvote. :/